# what does this schematic symbol refer to?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit

I have a schematic that has the intersected circles that IMOD and IBIAS arrows point to and I wonder about its meaning

[image]

edit :

if I know that this symbol is a current sink ..how can the Control IC change the current passing through the LD ? and how can I relate the resistor connected to IMODN to current in LD ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a symbol for a current, usually accompanied by an arrow to denote direction.Based on the fact that it is grounded, it can be inferred it is a sink. The naming IMOD suggests it is also adjustable by the internal logic of the IC.

Comment: if you know that this ADN2848 is used to drive a laser diode how can you interpret the direction of current ? I mean how the adjustable current from the Control IC change the current into LD ?

Comment: The current flows from top to bottom in the diagram.

Comment: Concur, because below it is a flat line indicating the lowest voltage in the gradient.  Probably a ground or maybe just a pcb trace of that shape.

Comment: Minor comment - the two NPN transistors are not a current mirror.  They are a differential pair used to switch whether the modulated current comes from the laser diode (LD) or from the IMODN pin that just has a dummy resistor in this case.